# How to fix "Angular CLI: 7.0.3 Unable to install node-sass'"

Tags: angular, npm, sass, command-line-interface, node-sass

When I run npm start it shows - cannot find module node-sass. And when I try to run - npm install node-sass --save, it gives me the following errors.

[image]

Comment: Hello, you didn't include any errors in your answer. Please paste any relevant Code and console output so we can try and help you. please read this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please paste the error as code, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

Download `win32-x64-48_binding.node` manually from https://github.com/sass/node-sass-binaries and put it in `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.5.3` then try `npm install node-sass` again